# shared_ptr pattern to own an object inside a function

Tags: design-patterns, c++11, shared-ptr

What's a good C++ **design pattern** to get an owning `shared_ptr` from inside a member function?

Inside my function I need to store a `shared_ptr` to `this` away and retrieve later -- in another scope. This naïve approach doesn't work:

```
void Foo::doSomething(shared_ptr<Bar> bar)
{
    bar->setFoo(make_shared<Foo>(this));
}

void Bar::setFoo(shared_ptr<Foo> foo)
{
    myFoo.reset(foo);
}
```

Now if I do

```
shared_ptr<Foo> foo(new Foo());
shared_ptr<Bar> bar(new Bar());
foo->doSomething(bar);
```

there's no way that I can later know if `bar->myFoo` is still valid.

The problem is that I'm creating a 2nd `shared_ptr` to the same `Foo` instance. But there's no way for me to access the `shared_ptr` from within the function because I only have `this`.

(Obviously the actual setup is more complex than this simple example)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for [std::enable_shared_from_this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this) and [std::enable_shared_from_this::shared_from_this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this/shared_from_this)